# Query to change time points to time span

Tags: sql, excel, qsqlquery

I have a simple dataset with 3 attributes. It looks like this

```
Time            flag          count

9/10/2017 1:00  Blue          0
9/10/2017 1:05  Blue          1
9/10/2017 1:10  Blue          2
9/10/2017 2:00  Blue          1
9/14/2017 1:00  Red           0
9/14/2017 2:00  Red           1
9/14/2017 2:30  Red           0
9/15/2017 1:00  Green         1
9/15/2017 1:10  Green         0
9/15/2017 2:00  Green         1
9/15/2017 2:50  Green         2
9/15/2017 2:55  Green         1
9/15/2017 3:00  Green         0
9/15/2017 3:30  Green         1
9/15/2017 4:00  Green         0
```

I need a sql query that give me the following output

```
total duration(minute)  flag    number of times >=1 duration when it's equal 
                                                        or higher than 1
60                      Blue          3              (10.09.2017  02:00:00 - 10.09.2017  01:05:00 )=55
90                      Red           1              (14.09.2017  02:30:00 -14.09.2017  02:00:00)=30
180                    Green          5              (15.09.2017  03:00:00 - 15.09.2017  01:00:00) + (15.09.2017  04:00:00 - 15.09.2017  03:30:00)=120+30=150
```

I appreciate your help.thank you

Answer (score 0):

The following shows how to window the data. The time-spanning is another piece of the puzzle.

```
SELECT flag, SUM(durationSinceLast) AS totalRelevantDuration, SUM(Count) AS relevantCount
FROM(
 SELECT flag, currentTime - prevTime AS durationSinceLast, Count
 FROM(
  SELECT flag, 
       LAG(Time) OVER (PARTION BY flag ORDER BY Time) AS prevTime,
       Time AS currentTime, 
       Count
  FROM T
 )x
)y
WHERE durationSinceLast > 1
GROUP BY flag
```

Revision per comment

```
SELECT flag, 
     MIN(Time) AS Begin,
     MAX(Time) AS End,
     SUM(1) Count --count 1 per record
FROM T
WHERE Count >= 1
GROUP BY flag
```

Comment: Actually the "number of times >=1" in output should be "number of times that count >=1", and that's what I need Greg

Comment: I think I understand now. Much simpler. See revision.